# How can I display a particular table cell on the screen regardless of scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this table, the `rowspan` of "left data" is too large, and depending on the scroll position of the table, the text of "left data" might be hidden.

How can I continuously display the text of "left data" on the screen regardless of the scroll position?

Of course, the actual table that I'm dealing with contains more data and has cells merged in various places.

```js
const myTbody = myTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
const myTr = document.getElementById("myTr");
const firstTd = myTr.children[0];

for (const i of [...Array(100).keys()]) {
  const td = document.createElement("td");
  td.textContent = `right data${i}`;

  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.appendChild(td);

  myTbody.appendChild(tr);
  firstTd.rowSpan = Number(firstTd.rowSpan) + 1;
}
```

```css
div.container {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#myTable {
  width: 300px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

#myTable thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>left header</th>
        <th>right header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTbody">
      <tr id="myTr">
        <td>left data</td>
        <td>right data</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: _Of course, the actual table that I'm dealing with contains more data and has cells merged in various places._ - we wouldn't know that. Can you provide an example of data that you might actually have? I'm assuming the idea is you want the text in "Left Data" to be at the top of the left column regardless of the rowspan setting. Will there be more content in the left column?

Comment: For the sake of posing the question, I've divided it into a left column and a right column, but in reality, there are many more rows and columns, with cell merges occurring everywhere. (Imagine a complex and large Excel file.)

Comment: I see your comment for the answer provided about the left column data. Update the code snippet here, not the codepen to show us your example.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the text "left data" in to a `<span>` element... Add a class, like `fixed-column`

```
<td><span class="fixed-column">left data</span></td>
```

Then add this ccs rules:

```
.fixed-column{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
```

The span element will keep in the center as you scroll down

Demo: [Fixed text in column](https://codepen.io/quakeglen/pen/jOegaQg)

Comment: Of course, if the only cell that needed to be fixed was the "left data", that would be fine... However, in reality, it includes many rows and columns, and cells are merged in many places. I've updated the codepen, so I think you can understand if you take a look.

https://codepen.io/ngmtine/pen/qBJepNx

Comment: You could use some kind of scrollspy script like this: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/scrollspy-static/
It can change class to a nav element links as you scroll down the page. It's intended to update links "active" class as you scroll down, but may be can be usefull to achieve your goal